# Is it possible to add text element in a grid Panel in extjs 2

Tags: extjs

I want to add a readonly text on the top of a GridPanel. Is it possible in extjs 2?

Something like "Note" in following example

Grid Header

Note: this is information abot grd

srno | name | xxx| yyyyy|zzzzzzz

Thanks,
User

Answer (score 0):

The Gridpanel has a 'header' property which reads:

header : Boolean
true to create the Panel's header element explicitly, false to skip creating it. If a title is set the header will b...
true to create the Panel's header element explicitly, false to skip creating it. If a title is set the header will be created automatically, otherwise it will not. If a title is set but header is explicitly set to false, the header will not be rendered.

Will this do the job?

EDIT as per comment:

Sure, there are examples on the ext.js api site, but it would be something along these lines:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    //your existing stuff
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    frame: true,
    title: 'This title will appear accross the header bar'
});
```

To specify more options for the header than the default classes and using the text from the 'title' property you can configure it like this:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    //your existing stuff
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    frame: true,
    headerCfg: {
        tag: 'h2',
        cls: 'x-panel-header',        // or whatever css class you want to apply
        html: 'Some custom text, I assume you can use tags in here'
    },
    headerCssClass = 'anotherClass' //this is additional styling
});
```

Have a look on the API for gridpanel, then look at the 'bodyCfg' config section, this shows the examples for header and footer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information dougajmcdonald! Can you please point out some example that use both title and Header for a gridPanel ?